# Angular.io & Ionic 2 attacking click event to button and passing variable to a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I am struggling to grasp how to do the following and would appreciate your help a lot any explanation.

What I want to create is a **button** with Ionic 2 that has a function attached to it, that takes an argument (**variable**) which is the name of a page. Once the button is clicked the view should move to the page passed as a variable using `navCtrl.push()` (I appreciate the problem has nothing to do with Ionic but it is more fundamental Angular/TS)

In home.html

```
<button (click)="moveToPage(pageName)" ion-button>Button</button>
```

In home.ts

```
moveToPage(pageName: String){
    this.navCtrl.push(pageName);
}
```

Apparently, the way I am writing it, in the HTML file I am not passing the "pageName" value but rather I am passing a variable of a type `undefined` that is called pageName.

It is most likely a silly question but I would appreciate if you help me understand the right way to going about solving my problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION]

**In home.ts**

*Import Page*

```
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular/navigation/nav-util';
```

*Add the goToPage(...){...} implementation*

```
moveToPage(pageName: Page)
{
    this.navCtrl.push(pageName);
}
```

**In home.html**

```
<button (click)="moveToPage('pageName')" ion-button>Button</button>
```

Initially, I was missing the single quotes around the variable name.

Next step is to move the function to a service so that it is accessible from all pages.